# How can I filter data on a rails index page using columns from a linked table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am looking for help with adding a search filter to an existing index page that normally shows all families in my geneaology database.

The family table holds zero or more father_ids and zero or more mother_ids that point to the Persons table which describes a person.

Here is the relevant code in the families controller (simplified until I get it to work).

```
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @families = Family.where("Person.find('fam_fatherid').first_name like 'bob%'") 
    else
      @families = Family.all.order(params[:sort])
    end
```

This results in a syntax error.  I have also tried several other ways to access the data, but to no avail.
Example : @families = Family.where ("fam_fatherid.firstname like 'bob%'").  This doesn't work because fam_fatherid is an integer and not an object (I assume). The error I get is:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: fam_fatherid.first_name

FWIW, here is the schema for the people table, just to verify that first_name is a valid column.

```
CREATE TABLE "people" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name_prefix" varchar, "first_name" varchar, "middle_name" varchar, "last_name" varchar, "name_suffix" varchar, "date_of_birth" varchar, "date_of_death" varchar, "gender" varchar, "notes" varchar, "sync_outlook" varchar, "sync_phone" varchar, "flags" varchar, "created_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL, "place_of_birth" varchar, "aliases" varchar);
```

This is the model:

```
class Family < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :childlinks, foreign_key: "child_family"
    has_many :people, through: :childlinks

    # attempting to link parents
    has_many :people, foreign_key: "fam_fatherid"
    has_many :people, foreign_key: "fam_motherid"
end
```

If someone can just point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.  I just started with Rails a few months ago, and I don't mind doing the research, but so far, I have spent many hours and just seem to be going in circles. I've been able to add a search to the people index page because the first_name (etc.) is a column in the Persons table and not a link to another table.
Thanks in advance, and I hope I've provided enough information.
Jere

Comment: Do you want to search only by one field (`first_name`)?

Answer (score 0):

Just join with related table and use `where` to search

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @families = Family.joins(:people).where("people.first_name LIKE ?", params[:search])
  else
    @families = Family.order(params[:sort])
  end
end
```

There is useful [gem ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). Using it you can quite easily create more powerful search fields

Comment: Using joins makes total sense. I guess I didn't think of that because I assumed that once you made an association in the model, rails would work it's magic and make that associated data available, either up-front, or more likely by constructing a sql query to obtain the data on the fly.  I also noticed your suggestion of a better way to check for the existence of a parameter.  Much appreciated.  I looked up ransack as well.

Comment: Hi @mechnicov, I tried but could not upvote due to my lack of reputation.  This was my first post. If I may ask one more question:  The search feature you suggested finds all children with the selected first name, which I find amazing, but my table has 2 links that I was trying to use for the search target; fam_motherid, and fam_fatherid, which should point to the persons table and then potentially match on their first_name.  I probably don't have the association right and nothing I've tried works.  I want to do something like where "father.first_name like ? or mother.first_name like ?".

Comment: Firstly you need to add associations with mothers and fathers. Depending on them different queries will be